# Disable UISearchController Animation

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Does anyone know how to disable the animation that causes the search controller to recede back up into the navigation bar. I cant find any solutions that work beyond ios 8.0.

```
self.searchContentsController.navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden( false animated: false);
```

is not working.

Comment: Have you tried `animationsEnabled = false` on the view?

Comment: @Michael On what view, UIView doesn't have this property.

Comment: UISearchController is the buggiest class in the whole UIKit, avoid it if you can. I also have similar issues with presentations and UIWindows because of this.

Comment: Use `UISearchBar`, not `UISearchController`.